# Using Text Field makes the app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, libgdx, textfield

So I've just started to learn Android Studio and LibGDX, so I'm not sure how to use TextField from Scene2d UI or if I'm using it correctly. The code below just crashes when I try to run it on the emulator.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private int screenHeight, screenWidth;
    private Skin skin;
    private TextField username, password;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        font.getData().scale(3);

        screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

        skin = new Skin();
        username = new TextField("Username", skin);
        password = new TextField("Password", skin);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();

        font.draw(batch, "Username:", (screenWidth / 2) - (screenWidth / 3),
            (screenHeight / 2) + (screenHeight / 12));
        font.draw(batch, "Password:", (screenWidth/2)-(screenWidth/3),
            ((screenHeight/2)+(screenHeight/12))-100);
        username.draw(batch, 1);
        password.draw(batch, 1);

        batch.end();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your problem is that you have no skin.

```
skin = new Skin();
username = new TextField("Username", skin);
```

You do create a new skin, but it is empty. TextField is looking for a TextFieldStyle when it is created, but there is none, so your app will crash.

Google around for how to create a non-null skin and that should solve your problem.